# Outputting specific values from an array and getting the correct values

Tags: c++, arrays

I've run into another issue while writing this code (with MUCH help from programmers here) and I'm having an issue with the program outputting the correct values. beadArrayTop should output something looking like this:

```
 4   *    4    *   4   *   4   *   4   *   4    *
```

instead it outputs that, only with 0's where the 4's should be.

beadArrayBottom does much of the same. I've tried putting the function printArray before beadArrayTop and beadArrayBottom, and even putting beadArrayTop and beadArrayBottom inside of printArray, but to no avail. Any hints on what I should do in order to make my output correct? Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>



using namespace std;

const int MAX = 14;
void line (int &cycleCounter, int &starCounter); //outputs a star followed by six spaces
void solidLine (); //outputs a solid line of stars
void smallerLine (); //ouputs a smaller line of stars
void board (); //outputs the mancala board, with numbers indicating the bins.
void binNumbersTop (); //outputs numbers indicating the bin # (Top only).
void binNumbersBottom (); //outputs numbers indicating the bin # (Bottom only).
void beadArrayTop (); //outputs the array for the top.
void beadArrayBottom (); //outputs the array for the bottom.
void beadArrayMiddle (); //outputs the array for the end bins.
void startArray (int beadArray [MAX]); //Creates an array of 14, with 4 in every slot except for 6 and 13.
void printArray (); //Outputs the array mentioned above
int beadArray[MAX];



int main ()

{





    board ();
    cout<<endl;












    cout<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;




}


//**********************************************//
void line ()
{
    int cycleCounter = 9;
    int starCounter = 6;

    while (cycleCounter > 0)
    {
        cout<<"*";


        int spaceCounter = 1;

        while (spaceCounter > 0)
        {
            cout<<"      ";
            spaceCounter = spaceCounter - 1;
            starCounter = starCounter - 1;
            cycleCounter = cycleCounter - 1;
        }
    }
}

//************************************************//
void solidLine()

{
    int loopCounter;
    loopCounter = 57;

    while (loopCounter > 0)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        loopCounter = loopCounter - 1;
    }

}   
//************************************************//
void smallerLine ()
{
    int loopCounterTwo;
    loopCounterTwo = 43;
    cout<<"*  13  ";
    while (loopCounterTwo > 0)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        loopCounterTwo = loopCounterTwo - 1;
    }
    cout<<"   6  *";
}   
//************************************************//
void binNumbersTop ()
{
    cout<<"*";
    int topNumbers = 1;
    cout << setw (7)<<"*";
    cout <<setw (4)<< 0;
    cout << setw (3)<<"*";

    while (topNumbers < 6)
    {
        cout <<setw (4)<< topNumbers;
        cout <<setw (3)<<"*";
        topNumbers = topNumbers + 1;
    }

    cout << setw (7)<<"*"<<endl;

}


//**********************************************//
void binNumbersBottom ()
{
    cout<<"*";
    int bottomNumbers = 11;
    cout << setw (7)<<"*";
    cout <<setw (4)<< 12;
    cout << setw (3)<<"*";

    while (bottomNumbers >= 7)
    {
        cout <<setw (4)<< bottomNumbers;
        cout <<setw (3)<<"*";
        bottomNumbers = bottomNumbers - 1;
    }

    cout << setw (7)<<"*"<<endl;

}

//**********************************************//

void beadArrayTop ()
{

    cout<<"*";
    cout <<setw (7)<<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[0];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[1];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[2];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[3];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[4];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[5];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (7) <<"*";

}
//***********************************************//
void beadArrayBottom ()
{

    cout<<"*";
    cout <<setw (4)<<beadArray[13];
    cout <<setw (3)<<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[12];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[11];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[10];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[9];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[8];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[7];
    cout <<setw (3) <<"*";
    cout <<setw (4) <<beadArray[6];
    cout<< setw (3) <<"*";

}
//***********************************************//

void board ()
{



solidLine ();
cout<<endl;


line ();
cout<<endl;



binNumbersTop ();


line ();
cout<<endl;
beadArrayTop ();

cout<<endl;
line ();
cout<<endl;


smallerLine();
cout<<endl;
line ();
cout<<endl;


binNumbersBottom ();


line ();
cout<<endl;
beadArrayBottom ();
cout<<endl;
line ();
cout<<endl;





solidLine ();
cout<<endl;


}

//*********************************************//

void startArray (int beadArray[MAX])
{
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; ++i)
    {
        beadArray[i]=4;
    }
    beadArray[6]=0;
    beadArray[13]=0;
}
//*********************************************//
void printArray ()
{
    startArray (beadArray);
    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    cout << beadArray[i];
    cout<<endl<<endl;
}
//*********************************************//
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [shadowing the variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `beadArray`:

```
void printArray ()
{
    int beadArray[MAX];
    startArray (beadArray);
```

Remove the `int beadArray[MAX]` declaration here, then the global value will be in scope, and you will be modifying it instead.

Normally, a compiler would warn you about this. If your compiler did not warn you about this, turn up the warnings. (For `gcc`, I like `-Wall -Wextra`, though other people like to turn up the warnings even further. This is a good minimum.)

Comment: I took out the int beadArray[MAX]; but I still get 0's when I output the arrays.

Comment: I've put up all of the code so you can see what happens here as well.

Comment: Something seems very strange that you're changing the contents of the array in a function called from `printArray()` -- perhaps the method should be named `initializeAndPrintArray()` or something more descriptive? (_Why_ do you initialize the array when you print it? That somewhat limits the utility of the array _and_ the printing function...)

Comment: I don't necessarily follow all that you're saying (I'm a beginner) but if it makes any sense, this program is for the game Mancala, and the arrays are for the bins and how many beads are in the bins. I wanted to put 4 beads in each bin except for bins 6 and 13, then later write more code on moving the beads throughout the bins.

Comment: Well consider what happens after three or four moves -- you need to re-print the array, and your `printArray()` function immediately calls another function that overwrites the entire contents of the array. This means the array can never be modified and _then_ printed -- the results are always destroyed.

Comment: I understand that! Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it so it outputs the correct amount of beads in each bin and it doesn't have to be re-written every couple of moves?

Comment: Remove the call to `startArray()` that is in `printArray()`. Initialize the array before you need it and then never again.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're creating two arrays, one on the stack and one global array.

```
int beadArray[MAX];

void printArray ()
{
    int beadArray[MAX];
    startArray (beadArray);

    ...
}
```

When you call startArray, it uses the local beadArray because it shadows the global array in printArray's scope.

You may want to learn about references and limit the scope of your variables as much as possible to avoid mistakes like this in the future.